# iPhone 4 app displays as support for iPhone 5 not for iPhone 4

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

After App has been launched in iTunes.In Requirements it says support for iPhone 5 .but app is supportable for iPhone 4 also.Dont know why it displays like that.Any guess what has gone wrong? Have i done any mistake while Uploading the build?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can disable supporting of iOS versions, but you can't disable launching on a device.

Comment: Did you add all Default.png, Default@2x.png and Default568@2x.png launch images?

Comment: I think its `OKAY`, you don't have to worry, since `iPhone5` is a new addition from Apple, and your app supports iPhone5 too thats what it means..

Comment: Which architectures did you build for (armv7, armv7s etc...)?

Answer (score 2):

By default, all iOS apps support the default resolution (320*480), but only few apps support the iPhone5 resolution (320*568).

If your App only supports (320*480), you won't see "optimized for iPhone5".
If you support both resolutions, you will see "optimized for iPhone5".

So, there is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

There is a strong reasons of it , let us understand it :-

In Build setting of a iOS Project , there is a option of **Target Devices**. Where we have to set minimum supported device of iOS. That means if you want it to support for iPhone 4S (iOS 5) then you have to select **Deployment Target as 5.0**. Which means that your app can support iOS 5 and above.

Hope this information helps you.

Answer (score 0):

By default when you create an Apple Project on XCODE IDE you need to choose that you are going to build it for iPhone/Ipad or universal.

Then if you cerate it for iPhone it would run by default on all the iPhone devices. viz. iPhone3GS, iPhone 4 seroes and iPhone 5 as well. But in iPhone5 your app will have a black border from top and botton because it runs on the screen size of 640 * 960.

Now beginning of june 2013 you need to incorporate and make changes in to your metadata to allow the App run on iPhone 5 in full resolution mode. else while processing the App to App store your App metadata will be rejected by Apple. and also you need to upload iPhone 5 specific screen shots in the size of 640 * 1136.

Let em know if you need any additional clarifications or have any doubts.

Regards

Rajeev